# C# Hashtable: Linked List or Open Addressing

Tags: c#, hashtable

I just had a Hashtable in C# explained to me as using a linked list for storing and retrieval but I thought this was for the dictionary class.  Is this correct?

Should clarify.  We are using .Net 4.5

Comment: As it is explained at [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379571(v=vs.80).aspx). The Hashtable is explained as using open addressing but this article is from many years ago.

Comment: From the [source of Hashtable](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/hashtable.cs,10fefb6e0ae510dd): "_The generic Dictionary was copied from Hashtable's source..._"

Comment: I see they are using open addressing.  As explained in their comments

Comment: @cubrr it might have been copied but the code works really differently Also Dictionary does not have/need a load factor. It does not even use one internally.

Comment: Very differently.  The only thing that HashTable uses is the DictionaryEntry Object  It does collision completely differently.  [DictionaryEntry Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.dictionaryentry(v=vs.110).aspx).